# How to calculate total impedance of two parallel conductors

Tags: impedance, conductors

I am trying to calculate the total impedance of two parallel copper wires under the following conditions:

1. The copper wires are thick
2. I want to include all relevant effects, including (but not limited to):

   - Skin effect
   - Proximity effect
   - Internal self inductance
   - External self inductance
   - Mutual inductance
   - Any capacitive reactances
3. For now we can ignore wavelength as it pertains to cable length as my specific question pertains to frequencies less than 100kHz and wire lengths less than 100m so these effects can be ignored.
4. The copper wires are parallel to each other, like zip cord.
5. The copper wires form a return circuit, i.e. current in conductor A is the same as the current in conductor B but in opposite direction.
6. Assume an AC voltage source at one end of this circuit with a frequency of f, and f being no more than 100kHz.
7. Assume no load on the other end of the circuit - I merely want to model the impedance due to the wire, not due to the load.
8. Assume solid cylindrical copper conductors in a PVC isolator just like zip cord, and the two conductors being very close together (approximately 2 - 6mm).
9. Assume the wire is between AWG10 and AWG28

I have done tons of research and know how to calculate AC resistance due to skin effect, I think I understand how to calculate the internal self inductance due to skin effect, and I have some other calculations for external self inductance.  What I do not have is a complete picture of

- which of above mentioned phenomena I need to consider
- which of those are duplicates, i.e. different names for the same phenomena
- which formulas to use for the rest of those phenomena

In the end I want to consider ALL phenomena that would have an effect of at least 0.001% in the given frequency range and wire specifications above.  So I want to solve:

Zac = Rac + j(Xl - Xc)

where Rac includes all resistances, Xl all inductances and Xc all capacitances.

Ignore the environment for now (i.e. any dielectrics / objects in the vicinity except for these two conductors).

I have reviewed these papers:

http://g3ynh.info/zdocs/refs/NBS/Rosa1908.pdf
http://g3ynh.info/zdocs/comps/Zint.pdf

And many others but get confused as per above.

Comment: If there is no load connected at the other end (i.e. open circuit) then what you have is essentially a capacitor

Comment: No, there is a load - a short circuit if you will.  Or put an 8 ohm resistor in - I just want to model the effect of a closed circuit ignoring the influences of the load.

Comment: Are you talking about the impedance looking into the 100m pair of wires from the point of view of the 100 kHz signal generator?

Comment: Correct - I basically want to calculate the delta Z of the circuit caused by the wires not being ideal conductors (0 Ohm impedance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Inductance:

[image]

The above is the formula for the inductance of parallel wires where s is distance between wires, L is the overall length and d is wire diameter and [here](https://www.eeweb.com/toolbox/parallel-wire-inductance) is a calculator that uses the formula.

### Capacitance between two parallel wires is:

[image]

[image]

---

For series resistance you will find many references on google for this and please note that it is ambient temperature dependant. There are plenty of references for skin effect also but not so many for the formula for proximity effect but hopefully [this reference from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_effect_(electromagnetism)) might prove useful.

---

Finally, once you have the resistance, inductance and capacitance you can use the standard formula for characteristic impedance (applies to any length of wire of course and is still valid down to DC): -

[image]

You haven't considered "G" but this is usually a very large resistance and its effect is negligible.

So now you have the impedance looking into an infitely long line of cable. However, you want the impedance looking into 100 metres of such cable so you will then have to work with reflection coefficients and the load impedance (stated as unloaded in the question) BUT YOU CANNOT ignore these load effects (and reflections) if you want a proper answer.

Reflections will occur with any incorrectly terminated cable: -

[image]

And these can effect results significantly even at moderate frequencies like 100 kHz. At 100 kHz the wavelength is 3 km but this is probably going to be more like 2 km. Major things happen at a quarter of this wavelength i.e. an open circuit can look like a short circuit and a short circuit can look like an open circuit so 500 metres is still pretty close for creating major errors when considering a cable that is 100 metres long.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I do have some questions.  The inductance formula you gave - does it include internal self inductance caused by skin effect?  External self inductance caused by the electromagnetic field in the conductor itself?  Or is it just the contribution of L2 on L1 and vice versa? As to reflections - assume the circuit is closed, and lets make the length 50m. Would that negate the effect of reflections due to the finite speed of light?

Comment: Might I just add -  [this is my work](https://www.waldonell.com/images/wires.pdf) thus far - I feel it is incomplete as it does not seem to consider mutual inductance or proximity effect.

Comment: The inductance formula is for the net inductance of both conductors assuming opposite currents i.e. it is less than the inductance of two disparate lines. Skin effect does not generate self inductance rather, self inductance produces skin effect. Making the length 50 m or 5 m does not eradicate the effect just makes it smaller.

Comment: Hmm I have two problems with that first inductance formula.  The first is that it assumes s >> d, so it will not necessarily be very accurate for conductors 1.024mm in diameter (AWG18) and separated by 4mm (typical for zip-wire) as 4mm is not significantly larger than 1.024mm. Second concern is that arbitrarily increasing s causes an ever increase in L, which does not make sense as I would expect that at some stage, a great enough wire separation would even out the inductance to some steady state value as the field strength weakens proportional to the square of the separation.

Comment: There may indeed be a better formula for inductance on line that is not approximate. The point I'm labouring to make is about the process of arriving at individual terms then using the characteristic equation formula and load reflections to  get the impedance.

Comment: @pwnell, Increasing the wire separation causes more space to be filled with flux.  The field due to each conductor depends only on the current through it, not on any other conductors laying around, so you are mistaken about separation decreasing field strength.  In fact, there is zero total field midway between the two conductors.  IIRC, the far field is inverse square and proportional to the separation between the wires and the cosine of the angle with the plane of the two wires.  With more flux, you have more inductance (defined as flux divided by current).

Comment: @Andy, suggest you review use of a Smith chart to calculate input impedance to a line that is terminated with a load.  Smith charts have been around since about 1939, and are still widely used to work transmission line problems.